# no such file or directory - datetimepicker.css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to include in my rails application a date time selector, looking around I found this: http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/index.php

but when I try to compile it I get the following error:

```
$lessc build/build_standalone.less datetimepicker.css
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/less-2.3.2/bin/lessc:100:in `read': No such file or directory - datetimepicker.css (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/less-2.3.2/bin/lessc:100:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/bin/lessc:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/bin/lessc:23:in `<main>'
```

I'm not too fresh with `less` could you please help me solve this?

the os is mac os 10.8.4

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved:

the second parameter was not pointing correctly to the css file.

the correct commandline is :

```
$lessc build/build_standalone.less css/datetimepicker.css
```

thanks :)